# Solution for print excel of 145 form in php

Tags: php

I have 145 different form for print excel option with different print structure, so i want to find solution for this to avoid from 145 print function, or 145 template file. 
I think one solution is to set completed setting and data of each form inside `config` when print setting function is called, but still i need 145 control statement (`if`) to check and set print setting with data in `config`. But something is not clear for me:
1- when we set `config-item` i think that item will be stored to memory and after function process end that item will be destroyed or no?

2- can we access that item inside another function (`print function`) that is called after we set item or no?
for any suggestion or solution thanks.

Comment: Hi @jones can you show me any two different print structure and your print function so that I can get a clear idea about this.

Comment: @KarthikN I have not started to develop print function yet, i want to find solution. Consider each form has unique format, form one with 6 column, form2 with 10 column with different style and data, and the same criteria for others, so i want to have one print setting function that provide format and data of each form for print function by setting as config item.

Comment: I too worked on the export function in it i used to have 5 different structures to export, during analysis I thought in future new structures will also be included so I save the export structure format columns in the DB, based on the selected export option i used to select the structure and data to fetch from the DB for avoiding individual print function for each formats.

Comment: @KarthikN I think for applying style and other formating it is good to use config file.